# Get all integers/dates between 2 values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given the following:

```
col val1 val2
A   2    7
B   43   46
C   1    3
```

How can I "explode" the two columns into:

```
col val
A   2
A   3
A   4
A   5
A   6
A   7
B   43
B   44
B   45
B   46
C   1
C   2
C   3
```

which is the combination of col and val between val1 and val2?

Comment: select them separately then union all

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select col1, val1, val2
      from t
      union all
      select col1, val1 + 1, val2
      from cte
      where val1 < val2
     )
select col1, val1
from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you just need tally table(here using [GENERATOR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html)) and JOIN BETWEEN:

```
WITH cte AS (
  -- generating range 1-100
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY seq4()) AS val FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 100))
)
SELECT t.col, c.val
FROM tab t
INNER JOIN cte c ON c.val BETWEEN t.val1 AND t.val2
ORDER BY t.col, c.val;
```